# Find keyword in Html and hide specific content using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have html code like below

```
<div id='p1'>
<p>First Paragraph</p>
<p>Abbot and Costello - Africa Screams</p>
</div>

<div id='p2'>
<p>Second Paragraph</p>
<p>Abbot and Costello - Frank/Meet</p>
</div>

<div id='p3'>
<p>Third Paragraph</p>
<p>addin</p>
</div>

<div id='p4'>
<p>Forth Paragraph</p>
<p>Begins</p>
</div>
```

I want to find a specific word like "addin" if it matches then I want to hide whole content with in `<div id='p3'>`.

How can I achieve this using jQuery?

Any help would be Appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$("p:contains('addin')").closest("div").hide()`

Comment: Thanks @Satpal. Why haven't you posted an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$("p:contains('addin')").closest("div").hide();`

This code working for me!

Answer (score -1):

**Try using:**

```
$("div p:contains('addin')").hide()
```

Comment: With this code `$("div p:contains('addin')").hide()` the content `<p>Third Paragraph</p>` is still visible.